# Debugging "unrestorable checkpoint" and UnsupportableException during Kryo stack deserialisation

Tags: corda

I have encountered a serialisation problem in Corda.  My new code path contains no new classes that haven't already been serialised/deserialised, but blows up with the following exception. Note that it contains no CorDapp specific classes in the stack trace, which makes it quite hard to figure out what the problem is.

Are there any hints/tips as to how to start to investigate what the underlying cause might be for this sort of exception?

Thanks :-)

```
com.esotericsoftware.kryo.KryoException: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
Serialization trace:
dataObject (co.paralleluniverse.fibers.Stack)
stack (net.corda.node.services.statemachine.FlowStateMachineImpl)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.ObjectField.read(ObjectField.java:144)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.CompatibleFieldSerializer.read(CompatibleFieldSerializer.java:147)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readObjectOrNull(Kryo.java:782)
    at co.paralleluniverse.io.serialization.kryo.ReplaceableObjectKryo.readObjectOrNull(ReplaceableObjectKryo.java:107)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.ObjectField.read(ObjectField.java:132)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer.read(FieldSerializer.java:540)
    at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.Fiber$FiberSerializer.read(Fiber.java:2137)
    at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.Fiber$FiberSerializer.read(Fiber.java:2067)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readClassAndObject(Kryo.java:813)
    at co.paralleluniverse.io.serialization.kryo.ReplaceableObjectKryo.readClassAndObject(ReplaceableObjectKryo.java:112)
    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.kryo.AbstractKryoSerializationScheme$deserialize$$inlined$use$lambda$1$1.invoke(KryoSerializationScheme.kt:97)
    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.kryo.AbstractKryoSerializationScheme$deserialize$$inlined$use$lambda$1$1.invoke(KryoSerializationScheme.kt:37)
    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.kryo.AbstractKryoSerializationScheme.withContext(KryoSerializationScheme.kt:80)
    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.kryo.AbstractKryoSerializationScheme.access$withContext(KryoSerializationScheme.kt:37)
    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.kryo.AbstractKryoSerializationScheme$deserialize$$inlined$use$lambda$1.execute(KryoSerializationScheme.kt:95)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.pool.KryoPoolQueueImpl.run(KryoPoolQueueImpl.java:61)
    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.kryo.AbstractKryoSerializationScheme.deserialize(KryoSerializationScheme.kt:94)
    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.SerializationFactoryImpl$deserialize$1$1.invoke(SerializationScheme.kt:111)
    at net.corda.core.serialization.SerializationFactory.withCurrentContext(SerializationAPI.kt:66)
    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.SerializationFactoryImpl$deserialize$1.invoke(SerializationScheme.kt:111)
    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.SerializationFactoryImpl$deserialize$1.invoke(SerializationScheme.kt:86)
    at net.corda.core.serialization.SerializationFactory.asCurrent(SerializationAPI.kt:80)
    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.SerializationFactoryImpl.deserialize(SerializationScheme.kt:111)
    at net.corda.node.services.statemachine.StateMachineManagerImpl.deserializeFiber(StateMachineManagerImpl.kt:715)
    at net.corda.node.services.statemachine.StateMachineManagerImpl.access$deserializeFiber(StateMachineManagerImpl.kt:63)
    at net.corda.node.services.statemachine.StateMachineManagerImpl$updateCheckpoint$2.run(StateMachineManagerImpl.kt:551)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at java.util.AbstractCollection.add(AbstractCollection.java:262)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.CollectionSerializer.read(CollectionSerializer.java:134)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.CollectionSerializer.read(CollectionSerializer.java:40)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readClassAndObject(Kryo.java:813)
    at co.paralleluniverse.io.serialization.kryo.ReplaceableObjectKryo.readClassAndObject(ReplaceableObjectKryo.java:112)
    at de.javakaffee.kryoserializers.UnmodifiableCollectionsSerializer.read(UnmodifiableCollectionsSerializer.java:71)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readObject(Kryo.java:731)
    at co.paralleluniverse.io.serialization.kryo.ReplaceableObjectKryo.readObject(ReplaceableObjectKryo.java:92)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.DefaultArraySerializers$ObjectArraySerializer.read(DefaultArraySerializers.java:392)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.DefaultArraySerializers$ObjectArraySerializer.read(DefaultArraySerializers.java:303)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readObject(Kryo.java:731)
    at co.paralleluniverse.io.serialization.kryo.ReplaceableObjectKryo.readObject(ReplaceableObjectKryo.java:92)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.ObjectField.read(ObjectField.java:125)
    ... 28 more
[INFO ] 17:02:38,664 [Mock network] (FlowStateMachineImpl.kt:432) flow.[66a8e516-7d9e-4ff3-a922-c80dda86768e].initiateSession - Initiating flow session with party O=Notary Service, L=Zurich, C=CH. Session id for tracing purposes is SessionId(toLong=763122305110574148). {}
[ERROR] 17:02:38,660 [CheckpointChecker-1] (StateMachineManagerImpl.kt:417) flow.[66a8e516-7d9e-4ff3-a922-c80dda86768e].deserializeFiber - Encountered unrestorable checkpoint! {}
com.esotericsoftware.kryo.KryoException: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Post some awesome help from Kat and Andras @ R3, we got to the bottom of this issue.  I've been asked to post this here so that there is a bit more google help!

**Solution (TL;DR)**

I had a map of objects, and for each of those objects I wanted to call to a method that essentially kicked off two sub flows (under the handleEvent method).

This was failing:

```
modelDataMap.values.forEach { it.handleEvent(event, this, flowLogic, notary) }
```

but this fixes the problem:

```
modelDataMap.values.toList().forEach { it.handleEvent(event, this, flowLogic, notary) }
```

I think that in the first case, Kryo deserialised the values as an unmodifiable collection and was then unable to add elements to it.  The toList resulted in Kryo creating a collection to which it could add values and everything was fine.

**How to figure this out**

I was aware of the code path that had changed that triggered this issue.  In my case I had a log line that preceded the stack trace that gave me a hint about where to start.

Andras pointed out two useful tools at this point.

*Missing @Suspendable annotations*

If you add the following flag to your test:

```
-Dco.paralleluniverse.fibers.verifyInstrumentation=true
```

you will be informed of methods in the stack that do not have the @Suspendable annotation.  This is actually really helpful.

*FlowStackSnapshot*

Andras has added a tool to FlowLogic that can be used to print out the stack.  We had the idea of adding a method to this that will iterate through the stack, recursively serialising and deserialising everything, so that it's possible to identify where the problem is coming from.

For the moment, adding this to a suitable point just before you blow up will atleast allow visibility of the stack from Kryo's point of view:

```
val snapshot = flowLogic.flowStackSnapshot()
```

Note that as of Corda 3.2, there is an @Suspendable missing in the code path for flowStackSnapshot so don't use the verifyInstrumentation flag with flowStackSnapshot for the moment :-)

Once again - huge thanks to Kat and Andras for helping to get to the bottom of this.